# MySQL sending data of dynamically created table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm creating a **MySQL** database to store data of tables which columns can change. This is why I'm using a **stored procedure** to dynamically create the tables.

My procedures allow creating, for example, a table with three double columns "ColumnA", "ColumnB" and "ColumnC".

Now I need to populate those tables with numbers from an application. This could be thousands of rows. I'm wondering how can I transfer the data **without doing a query per each cell**.

Up to now, my only idea is to create a stored procedure that, given the row ID and the column name, creates or updates the cell value.

However, it doesn't feel like a good idea considering that tables could have around 10 columns and 1.000 rows, which would require 10.000 calls to the procedure.

Comment: Creating tables with dynamic columns is usually a wrong design. Dynamic information should be in table contents, not table and column names.

Comment: Anyway, the solution is to create the `INSERT INTO` query dynamically, just like the way you create the table in the first place.

Comment: It sounds like you don't need a database at all, you just need a _file._

Comment: I'm having some users defining table format and some other users adding data for those specified formats. I need all this to happen in the cloud in a robust environment so data conforms to the specified format and is easily traceable.

Comment: This is why I'm avoiding using files. Also, declaring all dynamic data as rows has one drawback: If I create a table where to store column info and then another table to store values per each column, I would avoid using dynamic tables. However, I would be mixing all data together so, if one data format needs an adjustment, I would need to "touch" the data of all different formats as everything is stored together. It would be easier for mistakes to spread and corrupt all data. On top of that, this way of storing data does not improve communication as I still need to send each value separately.